# AWS Lambda response not in TwiML format

Tags: python-3.x, xml, amazon-web-services, twilio, twilio-twiml

I've been following this [tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-receive-and-reply-python-amazon-lambda) in order to set up a lambda function that replies to incoming texts from a Twilio webhook. The function seems to be working fine and receiving the text data, but when it passes the TwiML back to Twilio there's some kind of formatting issue. I'm getting a 12200 - Schema validation warning in the Twilio error log but I can't for the life of me find the issue with the TwiML. The message says:

`WARN "Content is not allowed in prolog."` at line 1, cols 1.

I've set up the API Gateway with the proper settings as stated in the tutorial. The Integration Request mapping template is set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and the Integration Response and Method Response templates are set to `application/xml`.

My lambda function is:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    return '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Response><Message><Body>Sorry, the command is invalid.</Body></Message></Response>'
```

This is the response I get when I send a request from Postman. There is a quotation and a newline character before the `<?xml` which appears to be the problem but as you can see in the `lambda_handler()` above, I don't believe I'm returning any quotations or `\n`.

```
"
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
<Response>
    <Message>
        <Body>Sorry, the command  is invalid.</Body>
    </Message>
</Response>"
```

Any help with returning XML in python or setting up the Lambda API Gateway would be appreciated as it appears that's where the problem lies.

Comment: What do you see using a tool like Postman, https://www.postman.com/,  to view the result? Is the output as expected?

Comment: Check for visible or invisible characters before the `<?xml ... ?>` XML declaration in *any* XML in play.  See duplicate links for further details.

Comment: @Alan I updated the question with the response I get in Postman. It looks like there's a newline before the <?xml could that be a problem and how would I get rid of that when the string I'm returning doesn't have the newline?

Comment: @kjhughes I had a look at both of those links but they didn't seem to work. Could this question be re-opened? As you can see in the `lambda_handler()` above, I don't have anything before the <?xml declaration. Any other advice would be appreciated!

Comment: The links weren't meant to "work"; they were meant to *inform*.  What they tell you is, in fact, born out by @Alan's helpful suggestion to inspect carefully the actual XML string being created: You do indeed have characters before the XML declaration.

Comment: @kjhughes My apologies, what I meant to ask was do you know why there appears to be a quotation and newline in my lambda response when I'm only intending to return the raw XML? I've been pouring over the API Gateway docs on AWS but I'm finding them a bit overwhelming.

Comment: I suggest that you experiment with your lambda handler: (a) Try using regular strings rather than multi-line f-strings; (b) Try to configure the response type to be another type such that the data is seen as XML, not a string to be escaped.

Comment: I will re-open your question since you're past the XML-level reason for the error and now on to having to resolve the Python or AWS lambda issue causing the undesired type/chars.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231563/discussion-between-graeme-and-kjhughes).

Comment: Let us know what you find out, on where the rogue LF is coming from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out, it was an issue with the API Gateway after all. I had it set up properly, but didn't deploy it correctly so all the changes I was making were not being implemented. Make sure your API Gateway is deployed so your mapping templates actually take effect!